# Problemas con borrado en laravel 7 con ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables, modal, laravel-7

Estoy creando una aplicación en laravel 7 con un crud a través de ajax, datatbles y modales. Mi problema realamente es que cuando intento borrar un elemento seleccionado hace todo el proceso pero en realidad no borra nada pero no me muestra ningún error en consola ni network del navegador ni laravel. Esto es lo que obtengo cuando seleccion el url del elemento borrado (No hay datos de respuesta disponibles para esta solicitud) Anexo mi código para sugerencias. Gracias de antemano.

```
Metodo destroy de mi controlador

public function destroy(Role $role)
{    
  $role->delete();
}
```

```
CRUD.js

$(document).ready(function($) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    const Toast = Swal.mixin({
        toast: true,
        position: 'top',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 3000,
        timerProgressBar: true,
        onOpen: (toast) => {
            toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer)
            toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer)
        }
    })

    //Delete
    $('body').on('click', '#modal-delete', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var route   =   $(this).data('route');
        console.log(route);
        
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            icon: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: route,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                })
                .done(function(data) {
                    $("#dataTable").DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    Toast.fire({
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: 'Data stored successfully'
                    });
                    console.log("success", data);
                })
                .fail(function(data) {
                    console.log('Error:', data);
                })
                .always(function(data) {
                    console.log("complete");
                });
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax({
                    url: route,
                    type: 'DELETE',
                })` acá no veo que envíes el `$role` que vas a eliminar y que espera el Controller

Comment: Saludos Cesar Romero. De heecho lo intente enviando la variable route por en la data del ajax pero igual no elimina Es decir quedando asi data: {route:route}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He descubierto la solucion a mi problema y este resindia en que no estaba pasando la variable $roles como se llamaba mi parametro en el arichivo web.php que se llamaba role. Solucion: cambie el nombre de la variable por $role y funciona. Gracias espero les sriva de algo.